# Pass arguments to dplyr functions

Tags: r, dplyr, lazy-evaluation

I want to parameterise the following computation using `dplyr` that finds which values of `Sepal.Length` are associated with more than one value of `Sepal.Width`:

```
library(dplyr)

iris %>%
    group_by(Sepal.Length) %>%
    summarise(n.uniq=n_distinct(Sepal.Width)) %>%
    filter(n.uniq > 1)
```

Normally I would write something like this:

```
not.uniq.per.group <- function(data, group.var, uniq.var) {
    iris %>%
        group_by(group.var) %>%
        summarise(n.uniq=n_distinct(uniq.var)) %>%
        filter(n.uniq > 1)
}
```

However, this approach throws errors because `dplyr` uses [non-standard evaluation](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html). How should this function be written?

Comment: As a matter of style, I would advise against using the dot in names in modern R, except in S3 generics. It’s terribly confusing. The naming convention used (amongst others) by `dplyr` is much nicer: `names_with_underscores`.

Comment: I'm aware that [Hadley Wickham's style guide](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Style.html) recommends the underscore notation, but the [Google R style guide](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Rguide.xml) promotes the period (although not for functions, which I have done here). In other languages the period is used for member access (eg. `myArray.length` in javascript), is there another conflict in R?

Comment: Google style guides are often terrible. In this particular instance, the problem is that it leads do ambiguities with S3 methods: is `some.class.method` a method `some` of class `class.method` or is it a method `some.class` of class `method`? Furthermore, it leads to inconsistent names when parts of your code are implemented in C(++), since that doesn’t support dots in names, necessitating mapping the backend function names to different R names.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You need to use the standard evaluation versions of the `dplyr` functions (just append '_' to the function names, ie. `group_by_` & `summarise_`) and pass strings to your function, which you then need to turn into symbols. To parameterise the argument of summarise_, you will need to use `interp()`, which is defined in the `lazyeval` package. Concretely:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lazyeval)

not.uniq.per.group <- function(df, grp.var, uniq.var) {
    df %>%
        group_by_(grp.var) %>%
        summarise_( n_uniq=interp(~n_distinct(v), v=as.name(uniq.var)) ) %>%
        filter(n_uniq > 1)
}

not.uniq.per.group(iris, "Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width")
```

---

Note that in recent versions of `dplyr` the standard evaluation versions of the dplyr functions have been ["soft deprecated"](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/compatibility.html#deprecation-of-underscored-verbs_) in favor of non-standard evaluation.

See the [Programming with `dplyr` vignette](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) for more information on working with non-standard evaluation.

Answer (score 26):

Like the old dplyr versions up to 0.5, the new dplyr has facilities for both standard evaluation (SE) and nonstandard evaluation (NSE). But they are expressed differently than before.

If you want an NSE function, you [pass bare expressions and use enquo to capture them as quosures](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43419398/845800). If you want an SE function, just pass quosures (or symbols) directly, then unquote them in the dplyr calls. Here is the SE solution to the question:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)

f1 <- function(df, grp.var, uniq.var) {
   df %>%
       group_by(!!grp.var) %>%
       summarise(n_uniq = n_distinct(!!uniq.var)) %>%
       filter(n_uniq > 1)  
}

a <- f1(iris, quo(Sepal.Length), quo(Sepal.Width))
b <- f1(iris, sym("Sepal.Length"), sym("Sepal.Width"))
identical(a, b)
#> [1] TRUE
```

Note how the SE version enables you to work with string arguments - just turn them into symbols first using `sym()`. For more information, see the [programming with dplyr](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) vignette.

Answer (score 19):

Here's the way to do it from *rlang 0.4* using *curly curly* `{{` pseudo operator :

```r
library(dplyr)

not.uniq.per.group <- function(data, group.var, uniq.var) {
  data %>%
    group_by({{ group.var }}) %>%
    summarise(n.uniq = n_distinct({{ uniq.var }})) %>%
    filter(n.uniq > 1)
}

iris %>% not.uniq.per.group(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)
#> # A tibble: 25 x 2
#>    Sepal.Length n.uniq
#>           <dbl>  <int>
#>  1          4.4      3
#>  2          4.6      4
#>  3          4.8      3
#>  4          4.9      5
#>  5          5        8
#>  6          5.1      6
#>  7          5.2      4
#>  8          5.4      4
#>  9          5.5      6
#> 10          5.6      5
#> # ... with 15 more rows
```

Answer (score 17):

In the devel version of `dplyr` (soon to be released `0.6.0`), we can also make use of slightly different syntax for passing the variables.

```
f1 <- function(df, grp.var, uniq.var) {
   grp.var <- enquo(grp.var)
   uniq.var <- enquo(uniq.var)

   df %>%
       group_by(!!grp.var) %>%
       summarise(n_uniq = n_distinct(!!uniq.var)) %>%
       filter(n_uniq >1)  


}

res2 <- f1(iris, Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width) 
res1 <- not.uniq.per.group(iris, "Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width")
identical(res1, res2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Here `enquo` takes the arguments and returns the value as a `quosure` (similar to substitute in base R) by evaluating the function arguments lazily and inside the summarise, we ask it to unquote (!! or UQ) so that it gets evaluated.

Comment: if I am getting the `Sepal.Length` and `Sepal.Width` from a list it doesn't work as it will be in the format of `"Sepal.Length"` and `"Sepal.Width"` what can I do then?

Comment: @KillerSnail  You should post a new question as this solution is specific to the problem mentioned in the OP's post

Comment: The question above from @KillerSnail is essentially the question I just asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46310123/r-dplyr-operate-on-a-column-known-only-by-its-string-name

Answer (score 8):

In the current version of `dplyr` (0.7.4) the use of the standard evaluation function versions (appended '_' to the function name, e.g. `group_by_`) is deprecated.
Instead you should rely on **tidyeval** when writing functions.

Here's an example of how your function would look then:

```
# definition of your function
not.uniq.per.group <- function(data, group.var, uniq.var) {
  # enquotes variables to be used with dplyr-functions
  group.var <- enquo(group.var)
  uniq.var <- enquo(uniq.var)

  # use '!!' before parameter names in dplyr-functions
  data %>%
    group_by(!!group.var) %>%
    summarise(n.uniq=n_distinct(!!uniq.var)) %>%
    filter(n.uniq > 1)
}

# call of your function
not.uniq.per.group(iris, Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)
```

If you want to learn all about the details, there's an [excellent vignette](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) by the dplyr-team on how this works.

Answer (score 3):

I've written a function in the past that does something similar to what you're doing, except that it explores all the columns outside the primary key and looks for multiple unique values per group.

```
find_dups = function(.table, ...) {
  require(dplyr)
  require(tidyr)
  # get column names of primary key
  pk <- .table %>% select(...) %>% names
  other <- names(.table)[!(names(.table) %in% pk)]
  # group by primary key,
  # get number of rows per unique combo,
  # filter for duplicates,
  # get number of distinct values in each column,
  # gather to get df of 1 row per primary key, other column,
  # filter for where a columns have more than 1 unique value,
  # order table by primary key
  .table %>%
    group_by(...) %>%
    mutate(cnt = n()) %>%
    filter(cnt > 1) %>%
    select(-cnt) %>%
    summarise_each(funs(n_distinct)) %>%
    gather_('column', 'unique_vals', other) %>%
    filter(unique_vals > 1) %>%
    arrange(...) %>%
    return
  # Final dataframe:
  ## One row per primary key and column that creates duplicates.
  ## Last column indicates how many unique values of
  ## the given column exist for each primary key.
}
```

This function also works with the piping operator:

```
dat %>% find_dups(key1, key2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid `lazyeval` by using `do` to call an anonymous function and then using `get`. This solution can be used more generally to employ multiple aggregations. I usually write the function separately.

```
library(dplyr)

not.uniq.per.group <- function(df, grp.var, uniq.var) {
  df %>%
    group_by_(grp.var) %>%
    do((function(., uniq.var) {
      with(., data.frame(n_uniq = n_distinct(get(uniq.var))))
    }      
  )(., uniq.var)) %>%
  filter(n_uniq > 1)
}

not.uniq.per.group(iris, "Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width")
```