# R dplyr operate on a column known only by its string name

Tags: r, dynamic, dplyr, quoting, rlang

I am wrestling with programming using `dplyr` in R to operate on columns of a data frame that are only known by their string names. I know there was recently an update to `dplyr` to support quosures and the like and I've reviewed what I think are the relevant components of the new "Programming with dplyr" article here: http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html. However, I'm still not able to do what I want.

My situation is that I know a column name of a data frame only by its string name. Thus, I can't use non-standard evaluation in a call to `dplyr` within a function or even a script where the column name may change between runs because I can't hard-code the unquoted (i.e., "bare") column name generally. I'm wondering how to get around this, and I'm guessing I'm overlooking something with the new quoting/unquoting syntax.

For example, suppose I have user inputs that define cutoff percentiles for a distribution of data. A user may run the code using any percentile he/she would like, and the percentile he/she picks will change the output. Within the analysis, a column in an intermediate data frame is created with the name of the percentile that is used; thus this column's name changes depending on the cutoff percentile input by the user.

Below is a minimal example to illustrate. I want to call the function with various values for the cutoff percentile. I want the data frame named `MPGCutoffs` to have a column that is named according to the chosen cutoff quantile (this currently works in the below code), and I want to later operate on this column name. Because of the generality of this column name, I can only know it in terms of the input `pctCutoff` at the time of writing the function, so I need a way to operate on it when only knowing the string defined by `probColName`, which follows a predefined pattern based on the value of `pctCutoff`.

```
userInput_prob1 <- 0.95
userInput_prob2 <- 0.9

# Function to get cars that have the "best" MPG
# fuel economy, where "best" is defined by the
# percentile cutoff passed to the function.
getBestMPG <- function( pctCutoff ){

  # Define new column name to hold the MPG percentile cutoff.
  probColName <- paste0('P', pctCutoff*100)

  # Compute the MPG percentile cutoff by number of gears.
  MPGCutoffs <- mtcars %>%
    dplyr::group_by( gear ) %>%
    dplyr::summarize( !!probColName := quantile(mpg, pctCutoff) )

  # Filter mtcars with only MPG values above cutoffs.
  output <- mtcars %>%
    dplyr::left_join( MPGCutoffs, by='gear' ) %>%
    dplyr::filter( mpg > !!probColName ) #****This doesn't run; this is where I'm stuck

  # Return filtered data.
  return(output)
}

best_1 <- getBestMPG( userInput_prob1 )
best_2 <- getBestMPG( userInput_prob2 )
```

The `dplyr::filter()` statement is what I can't get to run properly. I've tried:

`dplyr::filter( mpg > probColName )` - No error, but no rows returned.

`dplyr::filter( mpg > !!probColName )` - No error, but no rows returned.

I've also seen examples where I could pass something like `quo(P95)` to the function and then unquote it in the call to `dplyr::filter()`; I've gotten this to work, but it doesn't solve my problem since it requires hard-coding the variable name outside the function. For example, if I do this and the percentile passed by the user is 0.90, then the call to `dplyr::filter()` fails because the column created is named `P90` and not `P95`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm hoping there's an easy solution that I'm just overlooking.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have a column name in a string (aka character vector) and you want to use it with tidyeval, then you can covert it with `rlang::sym()`. Just change

```
dplyr::filter( mpg > !!rlang::sym(probColName) )
```

and it should work. This is taken from the recommendation at this github issue: https://github.com/tidyverse/rlang/issues/116

It's still fine to use

```
dplyr::summarize( !!probColName := quantile(mpg, pctCutoff) )
```

because when dynamically setting a parameter name, you just need the string and not an unqouted symbol.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking to do, thanks @MrFlick. Question: when I evaluate `str(rlang::sym(probColName))` it returns `symbol 95` (or other number according to the value of `pctCutoff`. What does the `!!` operator do in the case of a symbol? Is it converting it to a bare unquoted variable name?

Comment: A symbol is like a quosure without the environment. The !! Basically teats both symbols and quosures the same. A symbol is a bare unquoted variable name. That's what one used before tidyeval changed the paradigm.

Comment: It is interesting to me that the unquote operator `!!` is still required on a symbol, if a symbol is just a bare unquoted variable name, which is what `dplyr` verbs expect using NSE. Anyway, this solves a problem I've had for a while now, and with the updated quosure handling with the latest release of `dplyr`, will enable much more streamlined handling of generic arguments to functions that employ `dplyr` verbs. Thanks for the insight!

Comment: It really has more to do with when you want the symbol to be evaluated and when you want it unevaluated. The !! gives you more control over that.

Comment: Final follow-up: would there be any difference in using `as.name()` vs. `rlang::sym()` to accomplish this? I'm wondering if there may be a nuance related to the environment in which the expression is evaluated; I confess I still don't have my head wrapped around how environments come into play with quosures.

Comment: If you check the `?sym` help page, you can see there is a difference in how they handle encoding, but otherwise they are basically the same.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternate solution from Hadley's comment in the post referred to in MrFlick's answer (https://github.com/tidyverse/rlang/issues/116). Using `as.name()` from base R takes the place of `rlang::sym()`, and you still do need to unquote it. That is, the following also works:

`dplyr::filter( mpg > !!as.name(probColName) )`