# How to get function to work where dplyr is being used?

Tags: r, dplyr

I get an error when trying to call my function where dplyr is used inside the function. Does dplyr not work inside R functions?

```
all_df_yoy <- function(all_df, units) {
  all_df_yoy <- all_df %>% mutate(
    players_units_yoy = units)
}

us_players_all_df_yoy <- all_df_yoy(us_players_all_df, players_units_us)
```

I get the following error.

```
Error in compat_lazy_dots(.dots, caller_env(), ..., .named = TRUE) : 
  object 'players_units_us' not found
```

However, players_units_us does indeed exist inside the data frame​.

Comment: This will be a helpful resource to answer your question: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html

Comment: Also your function will not return a value as currently written. You can either use `return()` in the last line of the function, or if you just have the last line of the function be an expression not assigned to a variable it will return that value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass arguments to dplyr functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27975124/pass-arguments-to-dplyr-functions)

Comment: @qdread Actually it will return a value, it will just do so invisibly (ie, it won't print by default, but it's there). For example `f<-function() a<-2; b<-f(); print(b)` will return 2 but will not create a variable `a` outside the function scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a minimal reproducible example it's impossible to answer this question to your exact scope, but you need to utilize `tidyeval` to code functions in the same way that `library(dplyr)` does. Here is a brief example of what you have to do

```r
library(tidyverse)

create_new_col <- function(df, units) {
    units <- enquo(units)
    df %>% 
        mutate(players_units_yoy = !!units)
}

mtcars %>% 
    create_new_col(cyl)
#>     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb players_units_yoy
#> 1  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4                 6
#> 2  21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4                 6
#> 3  22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1                 4
#> 4  21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1                 6
#> 5  18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2                 8
#> 6  18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1                 6
#> 7  14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4                 8
#> 8  24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2                 4
#> 9  22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2                 4
#> 10 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4                 6
#> 11 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4                 6
#> 12 16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3                 8
#> 13 17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3                 8
#> 14 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3                 8
#> 15 10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4                 8
#> 16 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4                 8
#> 17 14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4                 8
#> 18 32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1                 4
#> 19 30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2                 4
#> 20 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1                 4
#> 21 21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1                 4
#> 22 15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2                 8
#> 23 15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2                 8
#> 24 13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4                 8
#> 25 19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2                 8
#> 26 27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1                 4
#> 27 26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2                 4
#> 28 30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2                 4
#> 29 15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4                 8
#> 30 19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6                 6
#> 31 15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8                 8
#> 32 21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2                 4
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

You can read more on this here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html

If you are new to programming in R, realize that this is a hurdle most users go through when beginning to develop their own packages. So don't worry if it doesn't click at first, become more familiar with R (try writing your functions using base R) and then come back to this topic.