# Create a function to report number of missing of one variable based on the value of other variable

Tags: r, na

I'm trying to create a function to report number of missing values of one variable. My code is as below:

`var1=c(1:10,rep(NA,5))`
`var2=c(rep(NA,10), 21:25)`
`var3=as.factor(c(rep(NA,3), rep("V",8), rep("U",4)))`
`var4<-c(rep(NA,3), 1:9,rep(NA,3))`
`data <- data.frame(var1,var2,var3,var4)`

So, the codes below gave me what I want, which is the count of missing values in one variable given the other variable's not missing:
`data %>% filter(!is.na(var3)) %>% summarise(Missing=sum(is.na(var2)))`
`data %>% filter(!is.na(var2)) %>% summarise(Missing=sum(is.na(var4)))`

But when I put them in a function, it didn't work:

```
count_missing <- function(data,a,b) {
  data %>% filter(!is.na(a)) %>% summarise(Missing=sum(is.na(b)))
}
```

For example:
`count_missing(data,var2,var4)` should give me:

```
Missing
1       3
```

But instead, it returned:

```
Missing
1       6
```

My guess is the `summarise(Missing=sum(is.na(b))` in the function doesn't take input from the pipeline.

Can anyone help me with this? Thank you!

Comment: Use `{{..}}`, see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56828881/3962914

Comment: Thank you Ronak, do I need any package to use {{}} operator?

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your function using the `{{}}` operator:

```
count_missing <- function(data,a,b) {
  data %>%
    filter(!is.na({{a}})) %>%
    summarise(Missing=sum(is.na({{b}}))) 
}
```

Usage:

```
count_missing(data,var2,var4)
```

Output:

```
  Missing
1       3
```

Comment: Hi langtang,

Thank you for your prompt response! I've tried your suggestion and it threw an error Error in UseMethod("filter") : 
  no applicable method for 'filter' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')" .

Comment: Do I have to install any package to use {{}}? I have rlang 0.4.11 already. Thank you!

Comment: I've tried it again and it worked. Thank you very much!